# SQL Query for records with ONLY one condition

Tags: sql

I have a table that features products with different media IDs. Most products have a number of media ID's like so:

```
ISISProductCode ISISMediaId
010015.000.000          9
010015.000.000          16
010015.000.000          10
010015.000.000          11
010015.000.000          12
```

How can I find products with ONLY 1 Media ID. I tried the query below but all that is bringing back is products that HAVE a Media ID of 10, but doesn't bring back products with ONLY a Media ID of 10.

```
select *
from dbo.Product
join dbo.Item
on dbo.Item.ISISStyleId = dbo.Product.ISISStyleId
where ISISMediaId = '10'
order by ISISProductCode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `ISISProductCode` and count all the `ISISMediaId` that are not `10` in a `having`
 clause.

```
select ISISProductCode 
from dbo.Product
join dbo.Item on dbo.Item.ISISStyleId = dbo.Product.ISISStyleId
group by ISISProductCode 
having sum(case when ISISMediaId <> '10' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
order by ISISProductCode
```